# How to create a List in a Session and submit before

Tags: primefaces

I need create a list of Phones in na  and submit before.

In my firt try the object came empty and the list shows a list of null objets

```
<h:panelGrid id="gridPhone" columns="5">
                        <h:outputText value="Numero:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{profileMB.phone.number}" size="10"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Tipo" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="selPhoneType" value="#{profileMB.phone.type}" >                                
                            <f:selectItems  var="phoneType" value="#{profileMB.listPhoneTypes}" itemLabel="#{phoneType.description}" itemValue="#{phoneType}" />                                                         
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{profileMB.addPhoneOnList()}" immediate="true" value="adicionar" update=":messageGrowl listPhones"/>                            
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center;width: 300px;">
                                <p:selectOneListbox id="listPhones" >
                                    <f:selectItems  var="phones" value="#{profileMB.phones}" itemLabel="#{phones.number}" />
                                </p:selectOneListbox>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:ajaxStatus style="display:block;margin-bottom:2em;height:24px;">
                            <f:facet name="default">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <f:facet name="start">
                                <p:graphicImage name="/images/spiffygif_30x30.gif" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <f:facet name="complete">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:ajaxStatus>
                    </h:panelGrid>
```

in my second try the object was filled but the Litt does update

```
<h:panelGrid id="gridPhone" columns="5">
                        <h:outputText value="Numero:" />
                        <h:inputText value="#{profileMB.phone.number}" size="10"/>
                        <h:outputText value="Tipo" />
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="selPhoneType" value="#{profileMB.phone.type}" >                                
                            <f:selectItems  var="phoneType" value="#{profileMB.listPhoneTypes}" itemLabel="#{phoneType.description}" itemValue="#{phoneType}" />                                                         
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:commandButton action="#{profileMB.addPhoneOnList()}" partialSubmit="true" process="gridPhone, listPhones" value="adicionar" update=":messageGrowl"/>                            
                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center;width: 300px;">
                                <p:selectOneListbox id="listPhones" >
                                    <f:selectItems  var="phones" value="#{profileMB.phones}" itemLabel="#{phones.number}" />
                                </p:selectOneListbox>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:ajaxStatus style="display:block;margin-bottom:2em;height:24px;">
                            <f:facet name="default">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <f:facet name="start">
                                <p:graphicImage name="/images/spiffygif_30x30.gif" />
                            </f:facet>

                            <f:facet name="complete">
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:ajaxStatus>
                    </h:panelGrid>
```

I have try sereval forms but dont work

:(

Comment: Please post your question using MCVE - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve